# ¿Cómo crear formulario con HTML y PHP?

Tags: php, html

Soy nuevo en estas plataformas, ya tengo el código en HTML y en PHP, sin embargo al momento de enviar un mensaje desde la página ya subida a un servidor no llega al correo que ingrese en PHP, me gustaría saber qué parte de código me hace falta.

**Código HTML:**

```
<form action="contact_me" method="post" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" required="required">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo" required="required">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
          <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="success"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
      </form>
```

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = 'alex.rodriguez7412@gmail.com'; /
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

return true;
?>
```

Gracias.

Comment: A priori deberías controlar el valor devuelto por [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php). "_`TRUE` si el correo ha sido aceptado para su envío, de lo contrario `FALSE`. Es importante tener en cuenta que si el correo es aceptado para su envío, NO quiere decir que el correo haya alcanzado el destino indicado._"

Comment: En el action del formulario te faltaría poner la extensión del archivo... `contact_me.php`

Comment: Muchas gracias, si después me di cuenta de la extensión faltante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando mandas el mail, ¿dónde está $headers?
Además, en el form, deberías poner en cada campo un value con la variable de php que recoge, para enviarla al presionar el botón Enviar, por ejemplo:

```
value="<?php $nombre ?>"
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Te faltan varias cosas:

### 1. En el HTML

Debes saber que la etiqueta que utilizan `$_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST` y demás familiares es la etiqueta `name` de los elementos HTML. Eso significa que si envías el formulario y luego haces `$nombre=$_POST['name'];`, lo que hará PHP será buscar entre los datos del formulario aquel que tenga la etiqueta `name='name'`. No la encontrará, porque tú estás usando la etiqueta `id` en los elementos del HTML.

Puedes usar ambas etiquetas, o puedes cambiar la etiqueta `id` por `name`, como prefieras. Pero `name` no puede faltar en este caso.

Por ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" required="required">
```

O, si quieres conservar la etiqueta `id`:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" required="required">
```

---

### 2. En PHP

Basta con aplicar las prácticas que enseña el Manual de PHP, cuando explica la función `mail`:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = 'alex.rodriguez7412@gmail.com'; 
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


$resultado=mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

if (!$resultado) {
    $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
}

return $resultado;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación, me quedo duda en la parte de heardes. 

En esta parte:
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

¿Se coloca un correo en específico? ¿El correo de destino?

Comment: @GaelRodriguez ahí se coloca generalmente el email del que envía el mensaje (tú e-mail) tanto en el `From` como en el `Reply to`. En este último puedes poner otro email si quieres que las respuestas sean enviadas a otra dirección diferente de la indicada en `From`