# ¿Porque no se esta enviando el email?

Tags: php

Hola me gustaria si me ayudan con este problema, ya he hecho la misma pregunta con esta ya son 5 veces, al intentar enviar un email en php no me llega, ya descargue sendmail y configure mi localhost este es mi codigo `

```
$email = mail("ejemplo@gmail.com","Sugerencia", "Este es mi correo: $correo. \n Sobre mi: $sobreTi");

                            if($email){
                                header("Location:gracias.php");
                                setcookie("unete", "true", time()+(30));
                            }else{
                                echo "\n<p class='bad'>Error</p>";
                            }`
```

Ya he intentado con este codigo

```
`ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting (E_ALL);
$from = "ejemplo@gmail.com";
           $to = "ejemplo@gmail.com";
           $asunto = "Comprobando el correo PHP";
           $mensaje = "El correo PHP funciona bien";
           $encabezados = "De:". $from;
           if (mail($to, $asunto, $mensaje, $encabezados)) {
               echo "El mensaje de correo electrónico fue enviado";
           }else{
               echo "No se envió el mensaje de correo electrónico.";
           }`
```

Y con otros codigos mas, y me gustaria si me dijeran los "campos" estrictamente necesarios en el sendmail por si es que tengo alguno vacio.gracias :).

Comment: ¿El código entra en el `else`? ¿Revisaste la carpeta de **Spam** en el correo?

Comment: El codigo si entra en el else, y ya vi la carpeta de spam y tampoco llegan ahi

Comment: Con hacer la misma pregunta cinco veces, todos pierden rastro de lo que ya has intentado y te lo haces más difícil. Eliges una de las cinco, la dejas vivir, borras las otras cuatro y en la que dejes, pones TODO lo que has intentado, completo. Si lo haces, yo le pongo recompensa a la pregunta y te ayudo. Si sigues abriendo la misma pregunta, las voy a votar negativas todas por hacer spam

Comment: Eso lo hize con la primera pregunta, la deje por mucho y nadie me respondio, ahorita mismo borro las otras preguntas.Y ya puse todo lo que intente en esta pregunta

Comment: Intenta poner encabezados, como sugiere el Manual de PHP, también, hay una forma de controlar errores en la función `mail()`, [en esta respuesta (**parte 2**) hay un ejemplo de ambas cosas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/134244/29967) intenta de ese modo y dinos si funciona o qué error imprime, Si no funciona, da más detalles sobre tu entorno (equipo local/servidor remoto), versión de PHP, qué framework/programas usas, etc. Si no manda el email desde local por ejemplo necesitas configurar un servidor de email desde `php.ini` y probablemente tener en tu equipo algún cliente de email.

Comment: Ya intente hacer lo que dijiste, no me sale ningun error, entonces esta es la informacion de mi entorno. uso un servidor local, mi version de php es 7.3.21 y  no uso frameworks

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  y pon el código actual. Si no está funcionando poniendo encabezados, puede que debas revisar tu configuración en `php.ini`

Answer (score 2):

Si no estas en una plataforma Windows, no te aconsejo el uso de `mail()` porque es [complicado de configurar](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-notes).
Si estás en Windows verifica estos valores en php.ini, obviamente personalizándolos con los tuyos.

> [ php.ini ]

```
SMTP=mail.tu_dominio.com
smtp_port=25
sendmail_from = una_cuenta@tu_dominio.com
```

Una función que, al menos a mi, me funciona para mandar correos es la siguiente:

```
<?php
function send_mail($subject, $msg, $from, $from_name, $to, $cc=Null) {
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '.$from_name.' <'.$from.'>'. "\r\n";
    $headers .= ($cc != Null) ? 'CC: '.$cc . "\r\n" : '';
    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
}
```

### PHPMailer

Si estás en Linux, o Windows, recomiendo [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/src)
Solo descargas y guardas los archivos del link en un directorio y los llamas desde PHP. También puedes descargarlo desde los [releases](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases).

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'ruta/de/phpmailer/PHPMailer.php'; 
require 'ruta/de/phpmailer/SMTP.php';

function send_mail($subject, $msg, $from, $from_name, $to, $cc=Null) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;    // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host       = "mail.tu_dominio.com";   // sets the SMTP server
    $mail->Username   = "una_cuenta@tu_dominio.com";     // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "La_contraseña";    // SMTP account password
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients(); // Limpia las direcciones anteriores
    $mail->setFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->addAddress($to);
    if($cc) {
        $mail->addCC($cc);
    }
    $mail->Subject  = $subject;
    $mail->Body     = $msg;
    $mail->send();
}
```

### Pruebas

Puedes llamar a cualquiera de las dos funciones, con un código como el siguiente. Si quieres agregar un correo CC, incluirlo como último termino, después de `$to`.

```
<?php
$subject = "Mensaje de prueba";
$msg = '<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <h3>Este es un correo de prueba</h3>
      <p>Este es un parrafo del correo de prueba</p>
    </body>
</html>';
$from = "mi_cuenta@mi_dominio.com";
$from_name = "Nombre para Mostrar";
$to = "cuenta_destino@dominio.com";
send_mail($subject, $msg, $from, $from_name, $to);
```

Comment: Gracias, ya descargue phpmailer y funciono :)